# key and value in zip

Tags: python, python-3.x, key-value

Note: I am new to Python.

I have a task to design a program that will output **foreign** number plates, but **only** if they're speeding. I may have done a few mistakes along the way, but I need help with the list Timestaken2 and dictionary Timestaken3.
The `#UK` and `#F` are just my notes for me to be able to have a quick look at which is a **UK** Number Plate and which is a **F**oreign.

```
import re

distance=750 #variable for the distance between the Camera A and B (in m)
speedlimit=70 # (mps)
NumberPlates=["DV61 GGB",#UK
              "DS11 EUBG 20",#F
              "5T314 10A02",#F
              "24TEG 5063",#F
              "TR09 TRE",#UK
              "524 WAL 75",#F
              "TR44 VCZ",#UK
              "FR52 SWD",#UK
              "100 GBS 12",#F
              "HG55 BPO"#UK
              ]

Enter=[7.12,7.15,7.24,7.45,7.28,7.31,7.18,7.25,7.33,7.38] #A list for the times of cars passing Camera A

Leave=[7.56,7.24,7.48,7.52,7.45,7.57,7.22,7.31,7.37,7.47] #A list for the times of cars passing Camera B

Timestaken=[]
Timestaken2=[]
Timestaken3={}

for enter_data, leave_data in zip(Enter, Leave):
    Timestaken.append(leave_data-enter_data)

Timestaken=["%.2f" % (leave_data-enter_data) for enter_data, leave_data in zip(Enter, Leave)]
Timestaken2=[s.strip("0") for s in Timestaken]
Timestaken2=[s.strip('.') for s in Timestaken2]

for key,value in zip(NumberPlates,Timestaken2):
    Timestaken3[key]=value

print(Timestaken3)

for item in NumberPlates:
    UK_Numbers=list(filter(lambda x: re.match("[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}$",x),NumberPlates))
    for item in UK_Numbers:
        if item in UK_Numbers:
            NumberPlates.remove(item)

print(NumberPlates)

for key,value in zip(NumberPlates,Timestaken2):
    Timestaken3[key]=value

print(Timestaken3)

print("10 cars have passed Camera A, then Camera B\n")

for key,value in Timestaken3.items():
    speed=distance/int(value)
    if speed>speedlimit:
        print(key,"is speeding with",speed,"mps")
```

I included the print()'s during the program to see what the program ends up doing. The second time I do:

```
for key,value in zip(NumberPlates,Timestaken2):
    Timestaken3[key]=value
```

I expected only the remaining NumberPlates which would be the foreign ones to be printed right after this code. Is the issue with Timestaken2 as it still has 10 values?

Please help me with any solutions you may have.

Comment: `for item in UK_Numbers:
        if item in UK_Numbers:` this is always true, by definition

Comment: `zip(NumberPlates,Timestaken2):` and then you are zipping a filtered list with a list of all the times

Comment: `for item in NumberPlates:` why?

Comment: `speedlimit=70 # (mps)` that's 250 km/h...

Comment: `speedlimit=70` is just experimental. I made the question to get the rest of the code sorted so I can start modifying the variables to what they need to be.

Comment: all this can be simplified as `speeds = {plate: speed for plate, leave, enter in zip(NumberPlates, [(distance / (leave - enter)) for leave, enter in zip (Leave, Enter)) if not re.match("[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\s+[A-Z]{3}$",plate) and speed > speedlimit }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure, but maybe you just want to make a new dictionary:

```
Timestaken4={}

for key,value in zip(NumberPlates,Timestaken2):
    Timestaken4[key]=value

print(Timestaken4)
```

Comment: Oh dear, I feel silly for not making another separate dictionary. This seems to work. Thank you very very much!

Comment: Either that or Timestaken3 ={} before this loop should clear the old junk.

Comment: That would not "clear" the old dictionary though, that would still create a new one and destroy the previous one. Btw @DTanya, when you do that, you have a hint that your code is too monolithic and should be split into separate functions.

Comment: Monolithic? Sorry, I'm a secondary school student. Emphasize on what you mean please.

Comment: defining functions will help you organize your code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are reusing `TimesTaken3` in the second part of your code. If you create a new dictionary `TimestakenForeign`  for speeding foreign cars, your code seems to work as expected:

```
print(NumberPlates)    

TimestakenForeign = {}

for key,value in zip(NumberPlates,Timestaken2):
    TimestakenForeign[key]=value

print(TimestakenForeign)

print("10 cars have passed Camera A, then Camera B\n")

for key,value in TimestakenForeign.items():
    speed=distance/int(value)
    if speed>speedlimit:
        print(key,"is speeding with",speed,"mps")
```